# Get <data android:scheme> attribute value from list of installed apps on android

Tags: android

On android I get the list of all installed apps. After that I want to launch any app using implicit intent. I need to know the value of data android:scheme attribute.
For eg In android.manifest if an app has

```
<data android:scheme="abc" />
```

I need to extract the string "abc" from the installed apps list so that I can launch only those apps with the

```
<data android:scheme="abc" />
```

using implicit intents.
Is there any api that can be invoked to obtain apps **android:scheme field** like we can obtain packagename, versioncode etc?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could post the code showing what you have already accomplished. Not only will it provide us with a starting point for us to help, but it will also help us determine if this is necessary. It sounds to me like you just want to create an Intent and create a new app chooser. Is this wrong?

Comment: List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm             .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
         for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
             Log.d("Launch Activity :"+ pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
From getLaunchIntentForPackage i can get launch intent with which i can launch another app by specifying the package name
But I dont want to specify package name.
Instead want to get something like packageInfo.data.android.scheme to obtain the <data android:scheme/> value. With this value I would like to launch my app not with packagename